# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exec() on string

Tags: php, mysql

Getting this error over and over.
I changed some things, but it still wont work.

Basically its a simple News system, where you can insert title, text and a Document to the database.

title and text getting inserted to the database, but the image_name and location not.

Also here the Database:

> CREATE TABLE "news" (
> "ID"  INTEGER UNIQUE,
> "TITEL"   TEXT,
> "NEWS"    TEXT,
> "CREATED_AT"  TEXT,
> "image_name"  TEXT,
> "location"    TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT) );

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>News hinzufügen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        require("mysql.php");
        
        //conc
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO news (TITEL, NEWS, CREATED_AT) VALUES (:titel, :news, :now)");
        
        // Titel, TXT
        $stmt->bindParam(":titel", $_POST["titel"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":news", $_POST["news"], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
        
        //Files
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        
        $exp = explode(".", $file_name);
        $ext = end($exp);
        $image = "news".'.'.$ext;
        
        $ext_allowed = array("pdf");
        $location = "uploads/".$image;
        
        if(in_array($ext, $ext_allowed))
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location))
            {
                $mysql="INSERT INTO `news` (image_name, location) VALUES('$image', '$location')";
 
                $mysql->exec($query); <----- ERROR LINE
 
                echo "<script>alert('Image uploaded!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.location='addnews.php'</script>";
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Only image to upload!')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='addnews.php'</script>";
        }
        
        

        // Time 
        $now = time();
        $stmt->bindParam(":now", $now, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "Die News wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt.";

    }
    ?>
    <form action="addnews.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="titel" placeholder="Titel" required><br>
        <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
        <input type="file"name="image" required="required" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Hinzufügen</button><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is correct, `$mysql` is a string. You have set it just one line before your error.

Comment: Use prepared statements for SQL queries with variables, like you did at the top.

Comment: Change `$mysql="INSERT INTO` to `$query="INSERT INTO`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `news` 
    (image_name, location) 
    VALUES
        ('$image', '$location')";

$mysql->exec($query);
```